# Is storing Javascript functions within Indexeddb a valid way of hiding javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, indexeddb

One of the requirements for the app i'm writing requires the application to work offline. For the app to function offline, i must write it's functionality in javascript, client side. There are some functions which the user shouldn't be able to see within developer tools. I'm using Angular 4 so the javascript code is already minified and uglified but the code can still be decoded.

The functions in question does some mathematical calculations.

My thought is to store the [javascript functions within Indexeddb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545031/store-a-function-in-indexeddb-datastore). Then the code cannot be read from the developer tools.

Is this a solution to hide JavaScript functions?

I know a keen user would be able to find a way to get into the Indexeddb on their machine. But it's better than nothing? right?

Comment: It's never a good idea to try to hide code from the user on a client. Put it on a server if it's that important. People that want to find your code will find it. In *vast* the majority of these cases, your code is not that important to anyone to begin with.

Comment: In general, if you don't want the client seeing your code, don't put it on the client.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides It's a requirement for the application to work offline. So there must be some client side functionality. If i wanted to do it server side, i would.

Comment: Use a [Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) then. That's exactly what it was made for.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I already do, but, can you store functions within a service worker?

Comment: Well, yes - if not for code what do you already use it for then?

Comment: you cannot hide any client side code from the client anyway, you can just obfuscate

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides You can use service workers for offline functionality.

Comment: That offline functionality is because Service Worker allows you to store files that you can access while offline.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides The code is still visible within developers tools, even if it's within  a Service Worker.

Comment: And what makes you think that it's not within IndexedDB? A determined attacker will just observe that it's working offline, then start setting breakpoints at your code and find out the code that you use. IndexedDB or not, you will eventually run that code on the client.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Well so far, i haven't found a way to view IndexedDB data directly via developer tools.

Comment: Determined attackers have far more experience at this than you do, even mediocre ones. Just because you can't do something doesn't mean that no one can. This is an easy task.

Comment: @Callum Both Firefox and Chrome *have* the functionality to inspect IndexedDB in their default developer tools.

Comment: @str I just did some research myself and that is the case. Indexeddb is not a valid option of hiding javascript functions. Case Closed!

Comment: @Callum Correction: The client-side is not the place to execute "private" code.

Comment: @str The requirement is for the app to function offline and requires the code. I'm happy for you to give me a client side solution other than putting it server side.

Comment: @Callum A requirement does not make it possible. For the record (and hopefully for the last time): **It is not possible to run private code on the client side with JavaScript**. The only "option" is obfuscation and that will not stop somebody from obtaining your code either, it will only make it harder.

Comment: @str There's always a way my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexeddb data can be viewed within Chrome, Firefox and Opera developer tools. Indexeddb is not a valid way of hiding javascript functions.

Comment: Even if it wasn't, you should quite simply forget that you can hide code that is run on the client.